# Хэшированный пароль в Spring Security в стандартной реализации аутентификации не работает после перезапуска приложения

Tags: java, spring, kotlin, spring-boot, spring-security

**Дано:**

1. `SpringBoot` приложение.
2. Используется для авторизации стандартная форма ввода логина и пароля.
3. Пароль хешируется через `BCryptPasswordEncoder`
4. Пока приложение запущено - можно поменять в БД пароль на результат вызова `passwordEncoder.encode("PasswordHere")` - и авторизовываться через форму входа.
5. Вот так выглядит подключение хэширования пароля:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true)
class WebSecurityConfiguration : WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter() {

    @Bean
    fun passwordEncoder() = BCryptPasswordEncoder()

    @Bean
    fun authenticationProvider(): DaoAuthenticationProvider =
            DaoAuthenticationProvider().apply {
                setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder())
            }

    @Autowired
    fun configureGlobal(auth: AuthenticationManagerBuilder) {
        auth
                .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider())
                .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder())
    }

    override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity) {
        http
                .cors()
        http
                .csrf()
                .disable()
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
        http
                .formLogin()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .permitAll()
    }
}
```

**Проблема:**

После перезапуска приложения ввод правильного пароля в форму входа выдаёт ошибку. При этом, если получить хэш пароля через `passwordEncoder.encode("PasswordHere")` и вручную его в БД вставить - всё работает до следующего перезапуска приложения.

**Вопрос:**

Таки что не так и как это исправить?

**UPD:**

Проблема не каждый раз воспроизводится. Иногда, после перезапуска работает. Однако чаше всего - не работает.

Comment: В смысле хеш после перезапуска отличается?

Comment: Хэш отличается каждый раз при вызове `passwordEncoder.encode("PasswordHere")`, однако это, по идее, нормально и не должно влиять на результат

Answer (score 2, accepted):

К сожалению причиной ошибки была моя невнимательность. У меня на поле для пароля была поставлена аннотация `@Converter`, в которой использовался класс-конвертер, который при каждом обновлении юзера в БД (полученного ранее из БД) заново кэшировал уже закэшированный пароль. Естественно, после этого проверка на совпадение в недрах спринговой авторизации выдавала ошибку несовпадения паролей.

Answer (score 1):

Хеш от passwordEncoder.encode() возвращается каждый раз разный, так как разные соли. Возможно ты сверяешь хеши методом Object.equals(), а для проверки равенства хешей используется специальный метод passwordEncoder.matches(CharSequence rawPassword, String encodedPassword), где rawPassword это пароль введенный юзером, а encodedPassword пароль из базы данных.

Comment: Я вручную нигде не сравниваю, всё сравнивается именно через `passwordEncoder.matches(CharSequence rawPassword, String encodedPassword)` в спринговой реализации авторизации.

Comment: На момент написания вопроса казалось, что больше кода показывать нет смысла) А потом я таки нашёл проблему - на поле с паролем был повешен конвертер, который при обновлении записи перехэшировал пароль(